# Varsnish cache - exclude IP by using wildcard

Tags: caching, ip, wildcard, varnish

Is there a wildcard in Varnish for IP pass thru?

I need to exclude my own IP from Varnish, I did it by adding the following to my /etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
acl passem {
        "183.89.36.93";
}

if (client.ip ~ passem) {
        return(pass);
}
```

and it works well. But my IP is dynamic and therefore I would like to use a wildcard, does Varnish support something like that? I need to give access to all IPs on: 183.89.*.*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
acl passem {
    "183.89.0.0"/24;
}
```